# how to customize the attribute (input type="file") HTML5?

Tags: html

Well, I've tried upload a file in a page .html, but I wanted to do some changes, first When I attach the file the name of document must be appear on the `<p>Name of the Document: </p>` and the size must be appear on the `<p>Size of Document:</p>`, here's an image to illustrate my example:

[image: here]

Someone have idea to how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by using the `files` property of the **Input FileUpload object**. Here is a multiple file upload example. If you need a single file upload, just delete the `multiple` property of the `<input>` element.

**HTML5 Code:**

```
<html>
    <body onLoad="showinfo()">
        <input type="file" id="upfiles" size="64" onchange="showinfo()" multiple>
        <br>
        <div id="fileinfo"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var showinfo = function(){
    var up = document.getElementById("upfiles");
    var info = "";

    if (up.files) {
        var upf = up.files;
        if (upf.length) {
            for (var i = 0; i<upf.length; i++) {
                var file = upf[i];
                info += "<p>"
                info += "<b>" + (i+1) + ". File Name: </b>";
                info += (file.name) ? file.name + "<br>" : "N/A";
                info += "<b>" + (i+1) + ". File Size: </b>";
                info += (file.size) ? file.size + " bytes<br>" : "";
                info += "</p>";
            }
        } else {
            info = "Select files to be uploaded.";
        }
    } 
    else {
        info = "Your browser does not support Input FileUpload object.";
        // You may add fallback function here.
    }
    document.getElementById("fileinfo").innerHTML = info;
};
</script>
```

Comment: you are Amazing, thanks, now I learn how to get values using JS, Thank you so much.